# Distribute iPhone App by Carrier

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

Google's developer console has a way to distribute an app by carrier.  I am trying to find the same thing for iTunes connect.  I need to make sure T-mobile users cant download my app.  Is there anyway to do this?  Can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Doesn't exist, not possible

Comment: why would you want that? That is the beauty of the iPhone is that you really shouldn't care what carrier the iPhone is on.

Comment: My app is a web app and I have been going back and forth with Tmobile for 3 months.  No Tmobile users can get to my webserver unless they switch to wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but its not possible. The only way you can limit the distribution of the your app is by country.